Data type for Elser Sparse Vector Embeddings in Spring Data
I'm generating sparse vector embeddings using elser model, i want to implement search using spring data based application, what datatype should i use for it.
Will the following code work?
    @Field(type = FieldType.Rank_Features)
    private Map<String,Float> sparseEmbeddings;

I'm using ES 8.13.4
I'm getting "searchResponse" is null error when querying and searching through my spring data based java application.

Maven is just a build tool used to manage java projects and their dependences. It can be applied to any java project and doesn't give us any additional useful information. You might get better answers if you specify the java library that you use. Based on your example it looks like you are using spring-data. Is this what you are trying to use? For the null searchResponse problem it would be helpful to see the code snippet that causes it.

Yes, I'm using spring data. It has been solved as I had to use jsonignoreproperties annotation to fix it.

I have updated your question with proper tags and clarified it a bit with this information. Hopefully it will now get more views. As I said in my previous comment I need to get more information about how you get null searchResponse to help you.
